# Visual Studio Code (VS code) user input while running and debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I've just started working with VS code on my Ubuntu OS and am trying to compile some c++ codes! My question is:
How can I use user input into my code? When I try to get something from user, the program does not let me to type anything at the Vcode window! Iss there any solution to that?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998471/how-to-build-and-run-c-code-in-visual-studio-code) SO question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build and run C++ code in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998471/how-to-build-and-run-c-code-in-visual-studio-code)