# Build OpenGL application in Visual Studio Code on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, visual-studio-code

My goal here is to get Visual Studio Code on my home machine (running Arch Linux) to build and run a C++ OpenGL application.  The code was actually written in Visual Studio 2013. It compiles/runs fine on Windows.

1. Is that possible?
2. If not, can I at least get VSCode's IntellliSense to recognize openGL, GLM, GLFW and GLEW

The most I've been able to gather is that I have to change my task.json file ([Link to Stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998471/how-to-build-and-run-c-code-in-visual-studio-code)) which I've done (with modifications for Linux terminal) but still nothing, I get this error in my output view:

```
g++: fatal error: no input files
```

As for the IntelliSense part of my question, I've got nothing other than I've gotta somehow fix my includePath (a message I get while hovering over the green squiggly line). So the question is then in what way do I edit it?

Comment: MSVS 2013 isn't the most standard compliant compiler.  If that is what you school uses and you need to make sure your code compiles there your going to need to use it.  Can you make a VM and install windows and MSVS 2013 on it?

Comment: I can, but I'm not paying for MSVS. My work around though is litterally to create a new project at school and copy the code into them. Because the main bits of my code are standard c++/openGL and I've seen classmates manage to get thier version of the assingment on MSVS 2017 working by doing this

Comment: You can get the free version of MSVS 2013 [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/) (scroll down a little)

Comment: Will attempt this solution tonight. thank you @NathanOliver