# How to set up tasks.json file in VSCODE to compile Fortran programs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran

I want to set up VScode (OS: Windows 10) to create and then compile programs written in Fortran 90/95. I can do this by typing in the terminal : `gfortran -o Example_exe Example.f90` and then `./Example_exe`. I don't want to have to write these lines every time, so I tried to set up my `tasks.json` file to automate a build routine using `gfortran` as compiler.
I found this tutorial : https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=360e0bde-0507-4de4-960c-2eae8fa8c782#gsc.tab=0 but the `tasks.json` file given is unclear.

**Can I have a `tasks.json` file setup to automate my build routine please ?**

I have installed the following extensions : Modern Fortran, Fortran IntelliSense, Code Runner, Fortran Breakpoint Support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. Assuming that you want to execute in debug mode, you should create a `tasks.json` and a `launcher.json` and place them in `.vscode/` at the root of your workspace.
Assuming the following file structure and a debugging mode with GDB for the execution:

root/

- .vscode/
- code/

  - Example_exe

This is what your tasks.json should look like:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [

        {
            "label": "compile",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "gfortran -o Example_exe Example.f90 -g",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "code/"
            }
        }
    ]

}
```

And then, the `launch.json`, which will identify `tasks.json` as a "preLaunchTask".

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations":[
        {
            "name": "Run my example",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\code\\example_exe.exe",
            "args": ["],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\code",
            "miDebuggerPath": "gdb.exe",
            "preLaunchTask": "compile",

        }
    ]
}
```

Launch the debugger by pressing F5 (or in the Run menu).

If you don't want to run in debug mode, have a look at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998471/how-to-build-and-run-c-code-in-visual-studio-code).

Sources:

- [How to build and run C++ code in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998471/how-to-build-and-run-c-code-in-visual-studio-code)
- awesome tutorial (for ubuntu, working for me with VSCode-gfortran-Win10)
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rj-kYb9nZ3g&ab_channel=LukasLamm.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question with such a detailled answer.

Comment: Thanks! So how do I create a task to run the exe?

Comment: HI @SimonWoodward, thanks for your comment, but I don't understand your question, could you be more specific? (What didn't you understand, or in what sense this answer doesn't fit your needs?). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @bbercz I didn't realize that you launch the debugger from the Run menu or with F5.

Comment: I also liked Lukas' tutorial and got it working in Windows 10.

Comment: All good @SimonWoodward, I updated the answer accordingly ;)