# Debugging Fortran code with gdb under Visual Studio Code in Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran

I saw other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68638271/how-to-set-up-tasks-json-file-in-vscode-to-compile-fortran-programs) that explain how to debug with gdb. But it still wont work with me. I installed the following extensions:

[image]

I created the following launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run GDB",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\run.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "preLaunchTask": "compile_with_gfortran"      
        }
    ]
}
```

and the following tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [

        {
            "label": "compile_with_gfortran",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "gfortran -o run.exe example.f90 -g",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }            
        }
    ]

}
```

Both json files are inside the folder .vscode. By hitting shift-ctrl-B the task builds correctly and creates the executable. When I click F5 to start the compiler, the preLaunchTask runs, the compiling buttons (step in etc...) show up but nothing attaches to the Fortran file, although I added breakpoints into proper locations. And nothing shows up in the debug console. Any suggestion?

Comment: If I remember correctly, one needs to also install some python package named along the lines of fortran-lint, so that one can carry out step-by-step debugging? Maybe you can follow that lead.

Comment: I was working on a file located remotely. That was the problem. No error message whatsoever. Once I moved the file locally everything was working. Strange because I could compile remotely with gfortran. So be careful if file is located remotely